# Full disk problem though it is not

Tags: disk

Disk full problem, but it is not in 12.04

Have tried to delete all trash contents permanent a lot of other things, but still full.
If looking into system monitor sometimes it looks like I've got 1GB free but system "eats" it up in a few minutes.

```
morgan@HP-PAVILION3:~$ df -h /home
Filsystem      Storlek Använt Ledigt Anv% Monterat på
/dev/sdb1         224G   223G      0 100% /
morgan@HP-PAVILION3:~$ df -i /home
Filsystem        Inoder IAnvänt  ILediga IAnv% Monterat på
/dev/sdb1      14671872  455212 14216660    4% /
morgan@HP-PAVILION3:~$ df -i
Filsystem        Inoder IAnvänt  ILediga IAnv% Monterat på
/dev/sdb1      14671872  455212 14216660    4% /
udev             211413     668   210745    1% /dev
tmpfs            215042     613   214429    1% /run
none             215042       3   215039    1% /run/lock
none             215042       6   215036    1% /run/shm
overflow         215042      46   214996    1% /tmp
```

Comment: I do not fully understand: the output of `df /home` says that you have no free space and use 100%. Where do you think is the 1G?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there is any process that should be consuming all that disk space? 
It happened to me, having my torrent client open and he just keeps on filling the disk. Check if you have the package manager downloading updates on the background and kill these processes.

```
ps -ax #Should list all the processes running, try and find out something, or post here the last lines of the ouput of this command
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I got the same situation where the ubuntu 14.04 was sucking up all the free space in my disk. I realize that happen just after I completely remove the *`zeitgeist`* from my installation.

Using `ps -ax` command as stated our mate in the answer above, you will be able to find the `villain`.
Then I just killed all the process related to *zeitgeist*. 
Now all my free space was back available again.